# Durrett Stationary sequence counterexample

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, stationary-processes

We know a Markov Chain $\{X_n\}$ with a stationary distribution $\mu$ as its initial distribution is a stationary process, because if $X_0\sim \mu$ a stationary distribution, then we know for each $n$, $X_n \sim \mu$, then by markov property we know $(X_0, X_1, \cdots, X_n)\sim  (X_m, X_{m+1}, \cdots, X_{m+n})$.

> Then Durrett said a special case to keep in mind for counterexamples
>    is the Markov chain $X_n: \Omega \rightarrow S=\{0,1\}$ with transition probability $p(0,1) =
>  p(1,0) = 1$, and stationary distribution $\mu(0) = \mu(1) =
>  {1}/{2}$.  $(X_0, X_1, \cdots) = (0,1,0, \cdots) \text{ or }
>  (1,0,1, \cdots)$ with probability $1/2$.

I am really confused, if the general statement is true, what is this counterexample implying, and why is this a counterexample?

Answer (score 2):

Durrett is not saying that this Markov Chain is a counterexample to the definition of stationarity: in fact he is demonstrating that this chain satisfies stationarity.

What he is saying is that it is useful to keep this Markov chain in mind when *picturing* what stationarity means. In particular this is a commonly used counter example to distinguish between stationary distributions, and limiting distributions.

Recall that a Markov chain has a limiting distribution if
$$\pi_j = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P_{ij}^n \qquad \forall \, i \in S,$$
exists. In particular that is if the limit does not depend on the starting state (and hence distribution) of the chain. Any chain that has a limiting distribution neccessarily is stationary (since $\pi$ can be shown to satisfy the stationarity property).

The converse however is not true: and this is what the counter example shows, since the limit above only exists if the chain is started from $\mu$, and not from an arbitrary distribution.

In general for finite, irreducible Markov chains

- A stationary distribution always exists.
- Existence of a limiting distribution implies stationarity.
- If in addition to being finite and irreducible the chain is also aperiodic, then a limiting distribution is guaranteed to exist.